# Conexión duplicada en Socket.io

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket, socket.io

He integrado socket.io en mi proyecto para obtener características en tiempo real. Casi todo está trabajando bien, pero cada vez que refresco la página, la conexión no se cierra y se duplica, causando conexiones múltiples para un solo usuario.

Este es mi evento en el servidor de sockets.

**Sockets_server.js**

```
socket.on('new-publication', function(data){
    console.log(data.pub);
    io.sockets.emit('new-publication', data)
})

socket.on('do-publication', function(data){
    console.log('Info: ' + data.nombre);
    io.sockets.emit('do-publication', data)
})
```

Este es el servidor de mi App:

**Server.js**

```
socket.on('new-publication', function(data){
                var datos_pub;
                console.log(data.pub);
                var currentdate = new Date();
                var datetime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1) + "-"
                + currentdate.getDate() + " "
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds();

                var publicacion = {
                    id_user : req.user.id,
                    publicacion : data.pub,
                    imagen : null,
                    fecha_pub : datetime
                };

                function formatoFecha(datestring){
                    var currentdate = new Date();
                    var fecha = new Date(datestring);
                    var hora;
                    var day = new Date(datestring);
                    var weekday = new Array(7);
                    weekday[0] =  "Domingo";
                    weekday[1] = "Lunes";
                    weekday[2] = "Martes";
                    weekday[3] = "Miercoles";
                    weekday[4] = "Jueves";
                    weekday[5] = "Viernes";
                    weekday[6] = "Sabado";
                    var daySemana = weekday[day.getDay()];

                    if (fecha.getDate() >= currentdate.getDate()) {
                        if (fecha.getHours() >= currentdate.getHours() && fecha.getMinutes() >= currentdate.getMinutes()) {
                            hora = 'hace un momento'
                        }else{
                            if (fecha.getMinutes()<10) {
                                hora = 'hoy a las ' + fecha.getHours() + ':0' + fecha.getMinutes();
                            }else{
                                hora = 'hoy a las ' + fecha.getHours() + ':' + fecha.getMinutes();
                            }

                        }

                    }else{
                        if (fecha.getMinutes()<10) {
                            hora = daySemana + ' ' + fecha.getDate() + ' a las ' + fecha.getHours() + ':0' + fecha.getMinutes();
                        }else{
                            hora = daySemana + ' ' + fecha.getDate() + ' a las ' + fecha.getHours() + ':' + fecha.getMinutes();
                        }
                    }

                    return hora;
                }

                function loadSelect(id) {

                    var resultado = {};
                    db.query('SELECT publicaciones.publicacion, publicaciones.fecha_pub, users.nombre AS nombre, users.image AS image FROM publicaciones JOIN users ON publicaciones.id_user = users.id where id_publicacion=' + id, function(err, rows, fields){


                        socket.emit('do-publication', {
                            nombre: rows[0].nombre,
                            publicacion: rows[0].publicacion,
                            fecha: formatoFecha(rows[0].fecha_pub),
                            image: rows[0].image
                        });
                    });
                }

                db.query('INSERT INTO publicaciones SET ?', publicacion, function(err, rows, fields){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    //db.end();
                    datos_pub =  rows.insertId;
                    loadSelect(datos_pub);


                });
          });
```

Lado del cliente:

**SocketJQ.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8081', {transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});

  socket.on('do-publication', function(data){
    console.log(data.image);
    var imageprofile = "http://localhost:3000/images/upload_images/"+data.image;
   var $items = $('<div id="card-container" class="grid-item"><div class="card"><img class="avatar" src="'+imageprofile+'"><div class="name">'+data.nombre+'</div><div class="date">'+data.fecha+ '</div><p class="card">'+data.publicacion+'</p></div></div>');
   // prepend items to grid
   $grid.prepend( $items )
     // add and lay out newly prepended items
     .masonry( 'prepended', $items );
  })

  socket.on('users-connected', function(data){
    console.log('Usuarios conectados: ' + data);
  })

  $('#Button-Post-Publication').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var publication = $('#Text-Area-Publication').val();
    var imagen = $('#upfile').val();
    console.log(imagen);
      if(imagen==""){
        socket.emit('new-publication', {pub: publication})
      }else{
        socket.emit('uploadfiles', {pub: publication, img: imagen})
      }

  })

})
```

**WebSockets_Server.js**

```
//websockets
var messages = 'Recibido';
var Usuarios = 0;

app.use(express.static('public'));

//Creamos el servidor websockets
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  //Se conecto al socket e incrementa la cuenta
  Usuarios++;
  //Vamos a decirle a todos los sockets cuantos usuarios se conectaron
  console.log('Usuarios totales: ' + Usuarios);
  io.sockets.emit('users-connected', Usuarios);

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    //disminuye la cuenta en los usuarios conectados
    Usuarios--;
    io.sockets.emit('users-connected', Usuarios);
  });

  socket.on('new-publication', function(data){
    //Nueva publicacion realizada, la envia a todos los sockets
    console.log('Mensaje del usuario: ' + data.pub);
    io.sockets.emit('new-publication', data)
  })

  socket.on('uploadfiles', function(data,buffer){
    var fs = require('fs');

    var fileName = __dirname + '/public/images/upload_images/'+ data.img;

    fs.open(fileName, 'a', 0755, function(err, fd) {
      if (err) throw err;

      fs.write(fd, buffer, null, 'Binary', function(err, written, buff) {
        fs.close(fd, function() {
          console.log('File saved successful!');
        });
      })
    });
    //Nueva publicacion realizada, la envia a todos los sockets
    console.log('Mensaje del usuario: ' + data.pub);
    io.sockets.emit('uploadfiles', data)

  })

  socket.on('uploadimage', function(data){
    //Nueva publicacion realizada, la envia a todos los sockets
    console.log('Mensaje del usuario: ' + data.pub);
    io.sockets.emit('uploadimage', data)
  })

  socket.on('do-publication', function(data){
    //Nueva publicacion realizada, la envia a todos los sockets

    console.log('Info: ' + data.nombre);
    io.sockets.emit('do-publication', data)
  })

});

http.listen(8081, function() {
  console.log("websockets corriendo en el puerto 8081");
});
```

Comment: el código que muestras del archivo Server.js es todo el que contiene?

Comment: No lo es todo, pero esos son los eventos implicados en el duplicado de información.

Comment: tienes el evento disconnect?

Comment: Así es, edite la pregunta para agregar el archivo "WebSockets_Server.js" que es donde se encuentra.

Comment: normalmente para controlar este tipo de situaciones, se usa un ID por cada conexión, así cuando se conecta alguien puedes detectar si es nuevo o si ya estaba (podría abrir otra pestaña y entrar aparte de recargar la página), para esto revisa https://socket.io/docs/server-api/

Comment: Voy a checar lo que me comentas. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

hace tiempo me paso lo mismo cuando estaba probando react.js y me di cuenta 
 1. Que no es recomendable usar react con jquery.
 2. Que una aplicacion a una sola pagina los eventos que manejaba
    con el "on" ejemplo

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', callback())
```

Este tipo de eventos le debes de hacerles el off

```
$(document).off('click', '.item', callback())
```

Creo que lo tuyo tiene algo que ver con esto, trata de hacer lo mismi sin Jquery o apagando los eventos despues de usarlos

Answer (score 0):

me paso lo mismo, quitale el doc.ready de jquery ejecuta tu codigo jq sin esperar que los demas componentes se carguen antes

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/200378)

Comment: no necesito formular una pregunta, tuve este problema y lo soluciones quitando el $(document).ready(function()=>{}

Comment: Puedes mejorar tu respuesta agregando una explicación a lo que propones, y también un ejemplo de cómo lo hiciste tú o adaptando el código de la pregunta de una forma que dices que funciona. Usa la sintaxis correcta y formatea el código como `codigo`. Te puede servir leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y también en [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) encontrarás cómo mejorar también la preguntas y respuestas en general.